# VBScript: Getting desktop shortcuts to perform special actions

Tags: vbscript, shutdown, msgbox, shortcut-file

Truth: I am completely new to this scripting thing and have reached an end-pass. I am trying to write a script that will not only create a shortcut on the user's desktop, but when the user clicks on the icon, I want them to be asked if they really want to shut down the computer and given the option to cancel the shutdown or proceed with the shutdown. So far I have searched to the end of my textbook and google. I can achieve creating an icon and having it perform a Windows native shutdown but not with my special intervening actions. I just don't know how to make the icon call back into the script for the select case routine... ***Sorry if it is a bit messy*** See below:

```
result = MsgBox ("Would you really like to Shutdown?", vbYesNo, "Shutdown?")
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

' Add Shutdown link to the desktop
Set linkShutdown = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\Shutdown.lnk")
linkShutdown.Description = "Shutdown the computer"
linkShutdown.IconLocation = ("%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,27")    
linkShutdown.TargetPath = "shutdown"
linkShutdown.WindowStyle = 1
linkShutdown.WorkingDirectory = "%windir%"
linkShutdown.Save

Select Case result
    Case vbYes
        MsgBox("Shutting down ...")
        Dim objShell
        Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0"
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox("Ok")
End Select
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you creating a shortcut to shutdown the computer when your script is doing it on its own?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Vbscript : **Ask2Shutdown.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyScriptPath 
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"Shutdown the computer")
Call AskQuestion()
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,Name)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If Name = "" Then
        Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-28"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,Msg,Title
    Title = "Shutdown the computer"
    Msg = "Are you sure to shutdown the computer now ?"& Vbcr &_
    "If yes, then click [YES] button "& Vbcr &_
    "If not, then click [NO] button"
    Question = MsgBox (Msg,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Run_Shutdown(30)
    else
        WScript.Quit()
    End if
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Run_Shutdown(N)
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Save your work because your PC will shut down in "& N &" seconds")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set x = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
x.ShutdownWindows
```

Gives you the Windows' Shutdown dialog.

You have two scripts in one file that you run sequentally. Put them into two files.